# Do I need to merge a branch in a bare repo?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-bare

In my setup I have three repos:

1. A bare repo on remote server (`/op/git/proj.git`)
2. A non-bare repo on remote server (`/var/www/proj/.git`)
3. A non-bare repo on local machine (`/var/www/proj/.git`)

The bare repo is origin to both ordinary repos on local and remote.

Whenever I do a commit on local, I do a local `push` to bare repo and then `pull` on ordinary remote repo and I get my changes on remote.

Now, I want to `merge` branch `A` to `master` which method should I use? (Assume `master` is the current branch on both repos)

**Method 1**
 1. `local$  git merge A`
 2. `local$  git push origin master`
 3. `remote$ git pull origin master`

**Method 2**
 1. `local$  git merge A`
 2. `remote$ git merge A`

I am not sure if the second method is all I need to do or not, in other words, since you cannot do things like `checkout` and `merge` in a bare repo, do you need to do anything to the bare repo after a `merge`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use method 1.

Method 2 would only work if `git merge A` will be a fast-forward on both local and remote. If any of the `git merge A` operations result in a merge commit (not fast-forward), the master branches will have diverged.

In general, merging the same branch in multiple locations is rarely useful in practice.

> do you need to do anything to the bare repo after a merge?

Just push to it, that's all.

Comment: This is the right answer (and upvoted), I just want to add a comment that the full merge process uses both the index and the work-tree to store all the intermediate results. While a bare repository does have an index, the very definition of "bare repository" is "does not have a work-tree", so the reason you *can't* merge in a bare repository is that it is missing a critical element for the merge process.