# How to merge local repository to a selected branch in bare

Tags: git, merge

We have a bare providing the branches "trunk", "release1", "release2" etc.
I have cloned me a local repository and all my changes were pushed to "trunk". Now I want to "merge" selected commits also to "releaseX".
I do not see how to do this.

I tried to reproduce this locally. I created me a local  repository "REPO" and worked on it and committed that.
Then I created me (locally) a bare named "BARE" and defined the "BARE" as origin to the config (`git remote add origin ../BARE`) and then pushed all my changes.
Then I created me another branch on the "BARE" by `git branch RELEASE`.
Next I worked on REPO and committed this and pushed to "BARE/master".

And here I am: The BARE/master and the BARE/RELEASE are different and I would like to merge master to RELEASE.

Hope this explains my question.

Comment: You cannot [merge in a bare repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18501139/7976758), you must [merge in non-bare](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40321630/7976758) and push to bare.

Comment: Is there some reason why you have to do this with a bare repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git it now. Did CherryPicking and pushed this to the BARE.

Comment: You do realize that cherry picking is not merging, right?

Comment: Also, cherry-picking requires a worktree too.  Why not just merge in a non-bare repository?